# How to add a fancy frame for an img if you only know its width?

Tags: html, css, frame, image

I have a small game, where the leaders of the previous and current week are show in a 3-celled HTML table at the bottom:

[image]

I resize the both fotos by hardcoding their width to 120 in HTML:

```
<td><img src="avatar1.jpg" width="120"></td>
```

I would like to ask my graphics guy to draw funny cartoon frames - to put around those 2 fotos. But I don't know how to place them technically and what assets he should draw for me.

How to handle this in CSS or HTML? Can I (ab)use the **td** background here somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a job for CSS3 border-image. See http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/ for a detailed tutorial and http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image for browser compatability.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating the frame so that it allows a variant `width` and `height`. Slice the image so that you can repeat the top, right, bottom, and left backgrounds and display the corners in their own `div` elements.

I would advise against setting a default `height` and `width` for your images as they can appear distorted. You can specify a **max** width so that they do not blow up your cells.

To set the `max-width`, do the following:

```
img { max-width: 120px; }
```

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm not a CSS-pro, how do you specify a max width? Also, the images aren't distorted currently - because I specify only width=120, but no height. My web page is at: https://apps.facebook.com/video-preferans/

Answer (score 0):

Going off Simon's answer, you could use the following CSS rule:

```
​img[width="120px"] {
  border: 10px solid red;
  /* border-image: url(border.png) 27 27 27 27 round round;   */
}​
```

As long as the `img` has its `width` set to 120px, it will match and get a border.